# The lower the framerate, the more the camera stuttters

Tags: unity-game-engine

‎‎‎‏‏‎ Hello, ‎everyone! Today I opened a recording program (OBS) and it lowered my FPS (understandably). However, I noticed that the camera stutters the lower the framerate (it even happens at 60 FPS, just less noticeably). The script is as follows:

```
 public Transform target;

 public float moveSpeed = 10f;
 public float offset = -1f;

 bool startFollowing = false;

 // Update is called once per frame
 void LateUpdate()
 {
     float targetYPos = target.position.y - offset;

     Vector3 newPosition =
     new Vector3(transform.position.x, targetYPos, transform.position.z);

     //ignore this if statement
     if (startFollowing)
     {
         //this makes the camera follow the player in only the Y axis
         transform.position =
         Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPosition, moveSpeed * Time.unscaledDeltaTime);   
     }
 }
```

So, what is causing this stutter? On lower framerates it gets pretty bad and noticeable, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I think it's also worthy to point out that the faster the player goes, the more jittery it becomes.

Comment: Why are you using unscaledDeltaTime ? If you're using deltaTime, it makes your code framerate independant, which is what you want

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for an answer, and I ended up on this [blog](http://www.rorydriscoll.com/2016/03/07/frame-rate-independent-damping-using-lerp/) where it tuned this guy's magical solution into this: (sorry for the formatting)

```
public Transform target;

public float moveSpeed = 10f;
public float offset = -1f;

bool startFollowing = false;

// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate()
{
    float targetYPos = target.position.y - offset;

    Vector3 newPosition =
    new Vector3(transform.position.x, targetYPos, transform.position.z);

    if (startFollowing)
    {
        //this makes the camera follow the player in only the Y axis
        float cameraY =
        Damp(transform.position.y, newPosition.y, 0.0025f, Time.deltaTime);

        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, cameraY, 
        transform.position.z);
        }
 }

    // Smoothing rate dictates the proportion of source remaining after one second    
    public static float Damp(float source, float target, float smoothing, float dt)
    {
        return Mathf.Lerp(source, target, 1 - Mathf.Pow(smoothing, dt));
    }
```

Works perfectly!